# how to implement debouncing in verilog

Tags: verilog, debouncing

I am using push button of DE2 board as asynchronous reset, but it fails to work.
This is my module for a n-bit register:

```
module regne (D, Clock, Resetn, Q);

    parameter n;
    input [n-1:0] D;
    input Clock, Resetn;
    output reg [n-1:0] Q;

    always @ (posedge Clock or negedge Resetn)
    begin
        if (Resetn == 0)
            Q[n-1:0] <= 'b0;
        else
            Q[n-1:0] <= D[n-1:0];
    end
endmodule
```

However, the reset fails to work. It does not do anything when I press the push button. I think it is caused by bouncing of push button. So how can I implement debouncing  in Verilog?

Comment: If you press and hold reset does it still not function property? If not, this is a connectivity issue and not a bounce issue. If a long press does cause a reset then check to see if the DE2 board is filtering inputs.

Comment: Are you sure that the push buttons are pull downs? Your code resets when the `Resetn` line is `0`. Try triggering on `posedge Clock or posedge Resetn` and making the if statement read `if (Resetn == 1)`.

Comment: I am sure that the push button on DE2 is pull down. And it does not work even if I press and hold button for a while

Comment: Check the pinout of the generated bit stream is correct - there are a variety of logfiles with this information in normally

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement debouncer for DE2 buttons. Its buttons (push buttons and switch buttons) have debouncer by themselves.

Replace

```
always @ (posedge Clock or negedge Resetn)
```

with

```
always @ (posedge Clock)
```

If it didn't work and you are sure about your pin assignments, make sure your board is working correctly.